# how to replace '0' with blank after using cumsum() , but should not affect more than 1 digit values containing '0' in it?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using cumsum() to create unique values based on condition.
Values are getting populated correctly based on condition. But how to replace 0 in single digit ?
Am i using my functions correctly ?

Code:

```
s = df1['Final'].cumsum().where(df1['Final'] == 'Yes')
df1['my_id'] = df1.groupby(s).ngroup()+1
```

Output:

```
Final   my_id
NO  0
Yes 1
NO  0
Yes 2
```

Expected Output:

```
Final   my_id
NO  
Yes 1
NO  
Yes 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use .replace method

```
df1.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)
```

See examples in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

Comment: works fine, but getting values in decimals, 2.0, 10.0, 20.0. How to get rid of decimals

Comment: df1.replace(0,'',inplace=True) works for me (use this instead of np.nan)